# Windowws 10 changed font size in SOME programs

Tags: windows, windows-10, fonts

Some months ago, Windows 10 changed the font size in some programs. I'm not talking about every font in wondows 10. It only changed in some programs like my Epson scanner, the program settings for my Yiynova (tablet digitalizer), ...

I attached some screenshots where you can see my problen. There are options that I can't press.

[example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAR7M.png)

[zoom example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2k6ih.png)

[example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGZEK.png)

[Scanner utility should appear like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvvK2.png)

[But it appears like this :-(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBxRm.png)

Comment: More information would help: was this after a Windows update? Had you changed settings? Installed new software?

Comment: I think that it happened after install one of the updates by Windows... but I'm not sure. Now I have Windows 10.0.17134

Answer (score 0):

Versions 1.0 and 1.1 of the .NET Framework supported automatic scaling in a straightforward manner that was dependent on the Windows default font used for the UI, represented by the Win32 SDK value DEFAULT_GUI_FONT. This font is typically only changed when the display resolution changes. The following mechanism was used to implement automatic scaling:

At design time, the [AutoScaleBaseSize](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.autoscalebasesize?view=netframework-4.7.2) property (which is now deprecated) was set to the height and width of the default system font on the developer's machine.

Try update .NET Framework to latest version

The .NET Framework version 2.0 surmounts previous limitations by introducing the following changes to the automatic scaling of Windows Forms:

[AutoScaleMode](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.autoscalemode?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Windows 10 comes with the latest version.

Comment: Then just try this out - https://www.intowindows.com/how-to-stop-auto-resizing-of-windows-in-windows-10/ , multitasking auto off  "Snap"

Comment: Will this work for you ?

Comment: Hi!

First of all, thanks for your answer. I've just checked that, and .NET Framework 2.0 was already installed (.NET Framework 3.5, wich includes 2.0)

Also, I see that  .NET Framework services (4.7) it's installed.

Comment: @stef I tried that but it doen't work.

Comment: try this - See link above in comments